# Qt TCP server/client communication

Tags: qt, tcp, network-programming

I want to send the array of data, e.g. data[] = {0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5}, from TCP server to client. I wrote the following code for that,

```
void server::sendData()
{
   QByteArray data;
   data.resize(5);

   data[0] = 0x1; 
   data[1] = 0x2;
   data[2] = 0x3;
   data[3] = 0x4;
   data[4] = 0x5;

  socket->write(data);  
}
```

Now the client is

```
void client::readData()
{
    qDebug() << "Bytes available: " << socket->bytesAvailable();
    QByteArray data = socket->readAll();
    for( int k = 0; k< 5; k++)
    {
       qDebug() << "Data " << data[k];
     }
}
```

But it's not working. How to read received array in client? 
The received byte count is 5, which is correct, problem is how to store data and read it.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean with **not working**?
Code looks OK. However you should be aware that you won't receive all bytes together in every case. You could also get one event with 2 bytes available and another with 3 bytes available.

Is your problem maybe your debug print, which interprets the data as character codes instead of numbers? Try

```
qDebug() << "Data " << (int)data[k];
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the commonly used IP-based network protocols (UDP, TCP) guarantee anything about how much data you'll receive at any time. In TCP the only guarantee is that if you get the data, it's in order, but as far as the protocol is concerned, it'd be perfectly fine for `readData()` to be invoked with just one byte available in the buffer.

It's incorrect that you're ignoring `data.length()`. Your loop can only iterate up to `data.length()-1`. There are no guarantees how large `data.length()` is. It won't be zero, but it may be 1, for example.